# Import example ^\d{3}-\d{4}$""

Tags: python

I`ve found an example which seemed to be very strange for me:

```
import re
for test_string in ['955-1212', 'ILL-EGAL']:
if re.match(r'^\d{3}-\d{4}$', test_string):
    print test_string, 'is a valid US local phone number'
else:
    print test_string, 'rejected'
```

The output is: 955-1212 is a valid US local phone number
               ILL-EGAL rejected

What exactly is "^\d{3}-\d{4}$" because when I change some digit, it changes the output to: 
955-1212 rejected
ILL-EGAL rejected

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: When I run this I get "955-1212 is a valid US local phone number
ILL-EGAL rejected" - but only after I indent the lines from the "if" onwards...

Answer (score 2):

It is a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) - it means:

```
^      from the start of the line
\d     match any number
{3}    repeated exactly 3 times
-      followed by a dash
\d     followed by a number
{4}    repeated exactly four times
$      followed by the end of the line
```

Changing the expression will either result in:

- Another regular expression that may or may not match 955-1212
- An invalid regular expression

You can learn more about regular expressions at places like [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: The final $ matches the end of the string - so locks it to the end.  This means that if you have any spaces before or after it will fail.

Comment: @Sean - correct - I missed that in my original answer - updated and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a regex.

`\d` matches `0-9`, `{3}` matches three occurrences of the previous pattern (so `\d{3}` is `\d\d\d`), `-` is just a dash, and `\d{4}` is just like `\d{3}` but with one more `\d`. The `^` and `$` characters denote the start and end of the string, respectively.

Regular expressions are more or less fancy search and replace: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

`^\d{3}-\d{4}$` translates to:

The string must start with digits (`\d`) x 3 (`{3}`),
followed by a dash (`-`),
then end with digit (`\d`) x 4 (`{4}`)

You can review [regular expression patterns here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), a language that allows you to express patterns of text.  The python library gives you ways to test if a string matches a regular expression, and pull pieces out of that string.

In this particular pattern:

- `^` means that the pattern must match at the start of the string (characters at the beginning of the string may not be skipped).
- `\d` means one single digit (one character from 0 to 9).
  ** The following `{3}` means to repeat the previous `\d` three times -- so match three digits.
- `-` matches a - character.
- `\d` again, match a digit...
  ** The following `{4}` means four times this time.
- `$` means that the pattern must match at the end of the stirng (characters at the end of the string may not be skipped).

So if you change the 3 or the 4 to something else, then the pattern will match a different number of digits, and that explains why it fails to match the string "955-1212".  For example, if you changed the 4 to 5 then the string "955-12123" would match, but "955-1212" would not.